# Powershell, split listing Get-Mailbox EmailAddresses

Tags: powershell, get

This is my Powershell command:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity <Display Name> -ResultSize Unlimited |
   List DisplayName, PrimarySmtpAddress, EmailAddresses | 
   Format-List -Wrap  PrimarySmtpAddress, EmailAddresses
```

But when there are more then 1 `EmailAddresses` for a user, it keeps everything together.

I Would like to have the `EmailAddresses` split after each SPACE so it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: How is the current output looks like?

Comment: The emailaddresses of 1 user are shown as:
EmailAddresses:
test@contoso.com, second@contoso.com, third@contoso.com, fourth@c...

It keeps the aliases together and doesn't put them on a seperate line

Comment: You could try `Get-Mailbox -Identity -ResultSize Unlimited | 
    Select DisplayName, PrimarySmtpAddress, @{l='EmailAddresses';e={$_.EmailAddresses  -split ','}}`

Comment: It keeps (smtp:test@contoso.com, smtp:second@contoso.com...) in 1 line

Comment: Its because on row represents one object / record.

Comment: So it is not possible to show it on another way?

Comment: At least I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-MailBox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select DisplayName, PrimarySmtpAddress, `
 @{Name='Email';Expression={ $_.EmailAddresses.SmtpAddress -join "`n" }} |
Format-Table -Wrap
```

Should do it.

---

The `EmailAddresses` property contains objects with many properties, there is no space to split on, because it's not a single string. So you can't use `-wrap` to change it, because it's not a string being wrapped. This answer uses a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to turn all the email addresses into a string, which can then be `-wrap`ped.

---

`-ResultSize Unlimited` is for returning lots of results, `-Identity <displayname>` is for returning a single result, using both together doesn't make much sense.

`List` is an alias for `Format-List`, so you're trying to pipe the output of Format-List back into Format-List, this is never going to do anything useful.

`Format-List` output is a property list, but you describe your desired output as a table, it's the wrong command to give that kind of output.